# Count only cells with number datatype

Tags: excel, count

I have 20 cells in MS Excel. There are both datatypes "number" and "string".
I want to count the number of cells, where is datatype "number".
I used countif(), but I do not know how to specify the criteria - "datatype:number"?
Please help.

In PHP I write this:

```
$number_of_numberic_cells = 0;
foreach ($cells as $cell) {
    if (is_numeric($cell)) {
        $number_of_numberic_cells++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
=COUNT(A1:A20)
```

it will count only the "number" cells.